# ASP.NET 4 OleDBDataAdapter Insert command inserts null values into table, instead of supplied values

Tags: asp.net, sql

I'm trying to import data from an excel file into my database. I have one OleDBDataAdapter for reading data from the excel file, and two OleDBDataAdapters for inserting the data into two tables in my SQL Server 2008 Express database. After executing the code, tables in the SQL database are filled with the correct number of new rows, but contain only null values. Debugging showed me that the data is read from the excel file correctly, and that the values are correctly inserted into the corresponding DataTable objects. Maybe I did something wrong with the insert command's parameters? The code is as follows:

```
    Dim fajl As String

    fajl = MapPath("fajlovi/" + Request.QueryString("ID"))


    Dim sConnectionStringExcel As String = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & fajl & ";Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;"
    Dim objConnExcel As New OleDbConnection(sConnectionStringExcel)
    objConnExcel.Open()
    Dim objCmdSelectExcel As New OleDbCommand("SELECT ZavedenKodPov, Ime, Mjesto, Adresa, JMBG, LicniBroj, ZaposlenKod, Nepoznat, Umro, Penzioner, Reon, VoziloProizvodjac, VoziloModel, VoziloRegistracija, Nekretnina, Datum, KontoBroj, NazivKonta, OpisPromjene, Dug, Pot FROM [Sheet1$]", objConnExcel)
    Dim objAdapterExcel As New OleDbDataAdapter()
    objAdapterExcel.SelectCommand = objCmdSelectExcel
    Dim objDatasetExcel As New DataSet()
    objAdapterExcel.Fill(objDatasetExcel, "XLData")
    Dim tExcel As DataTable
    tExcel = objDatasetExcel.Tables(0)

    Dim sConnectionStringDB As String = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=WORKHORSE\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=prinudna_testdb;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=korisnik;Password=**********"
    Dim objConnDB As New OleDbConnection(sConnectionStringDB)
    objConnDB.Open()

    Dim objCmdSelectDBDuznik As New OleDbCommand("SELECT ZavedenKodPov, Ime, Mjesto, Adresa, JMBG, LicniBroj, ZaposlenKod, Nepoznat, Umro, Penzioner, Reon, VoziloProizvodjac, VoziloModel, VoziloRegistracija, Nekretnina FROM tmpImportDuznik")
    Dim objCmdInsertDBDuznik As New OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO tmpImportDuznik (ZavedenKodPov, Ime, Mjesto, Adresa, JMBG, LicniBroj, ZaposlenKod, Nepoznat, Umro, Penzioner, Reon, VoziloProizvodjac, VoziloModel, VoziloRegistracija, Nekretnina) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)")
    Dim objAdapterDBDuznik As New OleDbDataAdapter()
    objAdapterDBDuznik.InsertCommand = objCmdInsertDBDuznik
    objAdapterDBDuznik.SelectCommand = objCmdSelectDBDuznik
    objAdapterDBDuznik.InsertCommand.Connection = objConnDB
    objAdapterDBDuznik.SelectCommand.Connection = objConnDB
    objAdapterDBDuznik.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("ZavedenKodPov", Data.OleDb.OleDbType.VarWChar)
    objAdapterDBDuznik.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("Ime", Data.OleDb.OleDbType.VarWChar)
    objAdapterDBDuznik.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("Mjesto", Data.OleDb.OleDbType.VarWChar)
    objAdapterDBDuznik.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("Adresa", Data.OleDb.OleDbType.VarWChar)
    objAdapterDBDuznik.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("JMBG", Data.OleDb.OleDbType.VarWChar)
    objAdapterDBDuznik.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("LicniBroj", Data.OleDb.OleDbType.VarWChar)
    objAdapterDBDuznik.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("ZaposlenKod", Data.OleDb.OleDbType.VarWChar)
    objAdapterDBDuznik.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("Nepoznat", Data.OleDb.OleDbType.VarWChar)
    objAdapterDBDuznik.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("Umro", Data.OleDb.OleDbType.VarWChar)
    objAdapterDBDuznik.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("Penzioner", Data.OleDb.OleDbType.VarWChar)
    objAdapterDBDuznik.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("Reon", Data.OleDb.OleDbType.VarWChar)
    objAdapterDBDuznik.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("VoziloProizvodjac", Data.OleDb.OleDbType.VarWChar)
    objAdapterDBDuznik.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("VoziloModel", Data.OleDb.OleDbType.VarWChar)
    objAdapterDBDuznik.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("VoziloRegistracija", Data.OleDb.OleDbType.VarWChar)
    objAdapterDBDuznik.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("Nekretnina", Data.OleDb.OleDbType.VarWChar)
    Dim objDatasetDBDuznik As New DataSet()
    objAdapterDBDuznik.Fill(objDatasetDBDuznik, "tmpImportDuznik")
    Dim tDBDuznik As DataTable
    tDBDuznik = objDatasetDBDuznik.Tables(0)
    Dim nRowDuznik As Data.DataRow

    Dim objCmdSelectDBKartica As New OleDbCommand("select ZavedenKodPov, Datum, KontoBroj, NazivKonta, OpisPromjene, Dug, Pot FROM tmpImportKartica")
    Dim objCmdInsertDBKartica As New OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO tmpImportKartica (ZavedenKodPov, Datum, KontoBroj, NazivKonta, OpisPromjene, Dug, Pot) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)")
    Dim objAdapterDBKartica As New OleDbDataAdapter()
    objAdapterDBKartica.InsertCommand = objCmdInsertDBKartica
    objAdapterDBKartica.SelectCommand = objCmdSelectDBKartica
    objAdapterDBKartica.InsertCommand.Connection = objConnDB
    objAdapterDBKartica.SelectCommand.Connection = objConnDB
    objAdapterDBKartica.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("ZavedenKodPov", Data.OleDb.OleDbType.VarWChar)
    objAdapterDBKartica.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("Datum", Data.OleDb.OleDbType.Date)
    objAdapterDBKartica.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("KontoBroj", Data.OleDb.OleDbType.VarWChar)
    objAdapterDBKartica.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("NazivKonta", Data.OleDb.OleDbType.VarWChar)
    objAdapterDBKartica.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("OpisPromjene", Data.OleDb.OleDbType.VarWChar)
    objAdapterDBKartica.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("Dug", Data.OleDb.OleDbType.Decimal)
    objAdapterDBKartica.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("Pot", Data.OleDb.OleDbType.Decimal)
    Dim objDatasetDBKartica As New DataSet()
    objAdapterDBKartica.Fill(objDatasetDBKartica, "tmpImportKartica")
    Dim tDBKartica As DataTable
    tDBKartica = objDatasetDBKartica.Tables(0)
    Dim nRowKartica As Data.DataRow

    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 0 To tExcel.Rows.Count - 1
        nRowDuznik = tDBDuznik.NewRow()
        nRowDuznik.Item("ZavedenKodPov") = tExcel.Rows(i).Item("ZavedenKodPov")
        nRowDuznik.Item("Ime") = tExcel.Rows(i).Item("Ime")
        nRowDuznik.Item("Mjesto") = tExcel.Rows(i).Item("Mjesto")
        nRowDuznik.Item("Adresa") = tExcel.Rows(i).Item("Adresa")
        nRowDuznik.Item("JMBG") = tExcel.Rows(i).Item("JMBG")
        nRowDuznik.Item("LicniBroj") = tExcel.Rows(i).Item("LicniBroj")
        nRowDuznik.Item("ZaposlenKod") = tExcel.Rows(i).Item("ZaposlenKod")
        nRowDuznik.Item("Nepoznat") = tExcel.Rows(i).Item("Nepoznat")
        nRowDuznik.Item("Umro") = tExcel.Rows(i).Item("Umro")
        nRowDuznik.Item("Penzioner") = tExcel.Rows(i).Item("Penzioner")
        nRowDuznik.Item("Reon") = tExcel.Rows(i).Item("Reon")
        nRowDuznik.Item("VoziloProizvodjac") = tExcel.Rows(i).Item("VoziloProizvodjac")
        nRowDuznik.Item("VoziloModel") = tExcel.Rows(i).Item("VoziloModel")
        nRowDuznik.Item("VoziloRegistracija") = tExcel.Rows(i).Item("VoziloRegistracija")
        nRowDuznik.Item("Nekretnina") = tExcel.Rows(i).Item("Nekretnina")
        tDBDuznik.Rows.Add(nRowDuznik)

        If Not (IsDBNull(tExcel.Rows(i).Item("ZavedenKodPov"))) Then
            nRowKartica = tDBKartica.NewRow()
            nRowKartica.Item("ZavedenKodPov") = tExcel.Rows(i).Item("ZavedenKodPov")
            nRowKartica.Item("Datum") = tExcel.Rows(i).Item("Datum")
            nRowKartica.Item("KontoBroj") = tExcel.Rows(i).Item("KontoBroj")
            nRowKartica.Item("NazivKonta") = tExcel.Rows(i).Item("NazivKonta")
            nRowKartica.Item("OpisPromjene") = tExcel.Rows(i).Item("OpisPromjene")
            nRowKartica.Item("Dug") = tExcel.Rows(i).Item("Dug")
            nRowKartica.Item("Pot") = tExcel.Rows(i).Item("Pot")
            tDBKartica.Rows.Add(nRowKartica)
        End If

    Next
    objAdapterDBDuznik.Update(objDatasetDBDuznik.Tables(0))
    objAdapterDBKartica.Update(objDatasetDBKartica.Tables(0))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not going to go through all of them, but when you do this:

```
objAdapterDBDuznik.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("ZavedenKodPov", Data.OleDb.OleDbType.VarWChar)
```

You also need to do this:

```
objAdapterDBDuznik.InsertCommand.Parameters["ZavedenKodPov"].Value = yourValue
```

You're adding the parameters, but not putting values in them.  That's what it looks like to me anyway.  Let me know if that doesn't help, or if I've missed something here.

Comment: Indeed the problem was not supplying values to the parameters, but instead of directly supplying them like you suggested, I've set the SourceColumn property of every parameter, i.e. after doing this:

`objAdapterDBDuznik.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("Ime", Data.OleDb.OleDbType.VarWChar)`

I also have to do this:

`objAdapterDBDuznik.InsertCommand.Parameters("Ime").SourceColumn = "Ime"`

Comment: @rnkjnk Either way.  Glad you got it worked out, I hope my answer helped in some way =)  You can use the up arrow or check mark next to this answer to indicate that if you wish.

Comment: Yes, thank you, your answer guided me the right way! It looks like I can't upvote your answer since i'm new here, it says I need 15 reputation to do it. Thanks a lot anyways!